# How to insert new row in between 2 rows in existing excel sheet using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I've created an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2010 to extract data from a MS SQL database and insert the data to a spreadsheet template I've created. I'm trying to get it to start writing the output at A3 but as I have a summary of the data in B11:C13 it always starts writing in A14.

I have also tried to set the OpenRowset parameter but as there is data below where I want it to start it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do what I want with the summary data included?

Answer (score 0):

a workaround:
the first one is to first dump your data in the worksheet and after insert your summary in B11:C13. or you can add this summary using a SSIS script to drive excel with OLE technology It allows you to make processes  from SSIS.Below a code snippet to insert in A6 : B6 cells:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                string sql = null;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

This summary can be added also from a macro (so you have to run it after dump data in excel file),but it is not interesting because it split your application on SSIS and Excel macro not so good... ;-)